# Why App Preview is in low quality after upload on the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

We have updated our App store description, screenshots and also added a Video preview. The video preview has been generated - as recommended by Apple - using iMovie with an "Export as App Preview" option.

We have 5.5 inches and 6.5 inches videos and both of them are very clean and high quality when played locally after the iMovie export.

After the Apple review was finished this morning, we went to check the App Store and found out that the video quality was really low.

What could be the reason for this low quality? Can it be just some server processing on Apple's side that is necessary before the HD version of the video is available on the store?

FYI > The app name is: Ikou - meet with your friends

Thank you for your feedbacks!

Comment: Apple is streaming the video with variable quality depending on network, device and probably a lot of other internal factors. Nothing you can do here.

Comment: I just sent an email to the apple support. I think it's not normal as after a few days, it's still really low quality and when I check other app video preview, it looks good

Comment: What was their response? I think the key argument here is that the preview videos of other apps play in high quality while our own video plays in low low quality. I thought this may be related for example my video being a bit larger (30Mb) than it could be, perhaps Apple doesn't compress and decompress it efficiently. And maybe other apps upload the already well compressed videos with small sizes (say 3 Mb) and then they can be streamed faster. Just an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you had the same issue as I but I also just uploaded a new App preview and released an update for my game and just like you I was worried when I found out the next day that my new app preview was playing in a terribly low resolution, certainly much worse than the resolution of the uploaded video.

Meanwhile, the app previews of other games were playing in good resolution so the 'you just have slow connection' answer didn't seem to make sense of course.
The good news is that your intuition was right, App Store apparently needs a lot of time to make the HD version of the video viewable, no idea why. Mine started to show the high resolution version after 2 days from the release date, in your case apparently even 3 days wasn't enough (may have to do with video size perhaps). Either way, if your problem was the same then of course you already know this answer already, but I'm adding it either way for anyone else who may find this thread with the same issue. Rest assured folks, it'll be replaced with a higher quality version after a few days.